# On a sine product integral

Tags: calculus, integration

The following integral came up in an expectation value computation in quantum mechanics:

$$I:=\int_{-a}^a\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{a}x\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)\text dx$$

There are some obvious subsitutions that can be made (e.g. $x\mapsto \frac{n\pi}{a}x$). Integration by parts seems relatively useless as you'll just end up with a sine and a cosine instead.

Comment: Euler's formula?

Comment: If $n$ is an integer you find $I=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\sin p . \sin q = \frac{1}{2} \left( \cos(p-q) - \cos(p+q) \right),$

$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-a}^a \left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{a} x \right) - \cos\left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{a}x\right) \right)  \ dx = \frac{a}{(2n+1)\pi} \sin(2\pi n)$$